# Cypress - if function with timeout

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I have problem. I want to try to find an element (1) for 60 second timeout. If Cypress will not find it, then it must not end as failed test but click on other element (2) and after that take screenshot and end as failed

It's because if this element (1) is not find it means that some feature in app failed. After I click on second element (2) I will find what was the problem and why it ended like that. That's because I want that screenshot after that.

Is there anyone who knows to resolve this?

Comment: Have you read: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Element-existence

Answer (score 0):

I think this should achieve what you are looking for -

```
cy.get("body").then(($body) => {
    // synchronously query for element
    if ($body.find("element").length == 0) {
        cy.get('locator').click()
        cy.screenshot(filename)
    }
    else {
        // do something else
    }
})
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Cypress allways timeout when trying to get the first locator and test end as failed doesn't go at else function.

Comment: I have updated my answer. now instead of directly getting the element we will try to find the element from the body tag and do the the actions based on its length. Can you try this once and let me know if it works ?

Comment: No, that doesn't work too. After I get to tab where I'm trying to get this element, app is calling other apps and it is waiting to response (so it's waiting sometimes 10 sec, otherwise 20 sec). So in body after get on this tab is never this element.

Comment: You can add `"defaultCommandTimeout": 60000` in your cypress json file, so that the cypress commands wait by default for 1 minute before timing out.

Comment: That doesn't work again. It not finds that element in body so continue in code.